# start_new_thread is not executing function for socket accept in python

Tags: python, windows, sockets, service

I have a working python script which opens a command prompt and listens on port 843 until a connection is received, and upon connection it is simply sending a file (flashpolicy.xml). I have included this below so that you can see the valid code I am basing mine off of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# flashpolicyd.py
# Simple socket policy file server for Flash
#
# Usage: flashpolicyd.py [--port=N] --file=FILE
#
# Logs to stderr
# Requires Python 2.5 or later

from __future__ import with_statement

import sys
import optparse
import socket
import thread
import exceptions
import contextlib

VERSION = 0.1

class policy_server(object):
    def __init__(self, port, path):
        self.port = port
        self.path = path
        self.policy = self.read_policy(path)
        self.log('Listening on port %d\n' % port)
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except AttributeError:
            # AttributeError catches Python built without IPv6
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error:
            # socket.error catches OS with IPv6 disabled
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind(('', port))
        self.sock.listen(5)
    def read_policy(self, path):
        with file(path, 'rb') as f:
            policy = f.read(10001)
            if len(policy) > 10000:
                raise exceptions.RuntimeError('File probably too large to be a policy file',
                                              path)
            if 'cross-domain-policy' not in policy:
                raise exceptions.RuntimeError('Not a valid policy file',
                                              path)
            return policy
    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, self.sock.accept())
        except socket.error, e:
            self.log('Error accepting connection: %s' % (e[1],))
    def handle(self, conn, addr):
        addrstr = '%s:%s' % (addr[0],addr[1])
        try:
            self.log('Connection from %s' % (addrstr,))
            with contextlib.closing(conn):
                # It's possible that we won't get the entire request in
                # a single recv, but very unlikely.
                request = conn.recv(1024).strip()
                if request != '<policy-file-request/>\0':
                    self.log('Unrecognized request from %s: %s' % (addrstr, request))
                    return
                self.log('Valid request received from %s' % (addrstr,))
                conn.sendall(self.policy)
                self.log('Sent policy file to %s' % (addrstr,))
        except socket.error, e:
            self.log('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))
        except Exception, e:
            self.log('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))
    def log(self, str):
        print >>sys.stderr, str

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage = '%prog [--port=PORT] [--file=FILE]',
                                   version='%prog ' + str(VERSION))
    parser.add_option('-p', '--port', dest='port', type=int, default=843,
                      help='listen on port PORT', metavar='PORT')
    parser.add_option('-f', '--file', dest='path', type="string", default="flashpolicy.xml",
                      help='something FILE', metavar='FILE')
    opts, args = parser.parse_args()
    if args:
        parser.error('No arguments are needed. See help.')
    if not opts.path:
        parser.error('File must be specified. See help.')

    try:
        policy_server(opts.port, opts.path).run()
    except Exception, e:
        print >> sys.stderr, e
        sys.exit(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like this to be installed as a service so that I can run this constantly in the background without an annoying command prompt window requiring to be open constantly, so I found another script that installs python scripts as a service, and am attempting to use that to install this as a service.

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import pythoncom
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import sys
import optparse
import thread
import exceptions
import contextlib
import logging


class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "flaspsrv"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Flash Policy Server"
    _svc_description_ = "Initialize Flash Policy Server"

    def __init__(self,args):
        logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Uploads\\testing.log', level=logging.DEBUG, filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except AttributeError:
            # AttributeError catches Python built without IPv6
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error:
            # socket.error catches OS with IPv6 disabled
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            logging.info('Listening on port 843')
            self.sock.bind(('', 843))
            self.sock.listen(5)

        try:
            while True:
                thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, self.sock.accept())
        except socket.error, e:
            logging.info('Error accepting connection: %s' % (e[1],))

    def handle(self, conn, addr):
        logging.info('Temp2')
        addrstr = '%s:%s' % (addr[0],addr[1])
        try:
            logging.info('Connection from %s' % (addrstr,))
            with contextlib.closing(conn):
                # It's possible that we won't get the entire request in
                # a single recv, but very unlikely.
                request = conn.recv(1024).strip()
                if request != '<policy-file-request/>\0':
                    logging.info('Unrecognized request from %s: %s' % (addrstr, request))
                    return
                logging.info('Valid request received from %s' % (addrstr,))
                fo = file('flashpolicy.xml', 'rb')
                conn.sendall(fo.read(10001))
                logging.info('Sent policy file to %s' % (addrstr,))
        except socket.error, e:
            logging.info('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))
        except Exception, e:
            logging.info('Error handling connection from %s: %s' % (addrstr, e[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

The service installs correctly, I can start the service, it will show as running and the logging will verify that it has executed to the while True: start new thread infinite loop. The accept() function should be sending the two parameters to "handle" as expected and has not been majorly modified from the original code, but as soon as I try to make a "connection" the process STOPS and the "Temp2" log statement at the beginning of "handle" is never executed.  Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: One minor thing: accept() can raise non-fatal exceptions, so the exception handler should be inside the loop. Another thing: setsockopt() and bind() are inside the socket.error exception handler. If your Python does not support IPv6, it will execute the AttributeError exception handler that does nothing except creating a socket that is never bound to any port.